# Why is my wordpress sql query returning no results?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I wrote this query to output results from multiple wordpress tables but for some reason it just returns blank. Maybe a fresh set of eyes can spot issues with my query.

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT 
            u.ID,
            u.user_email,
            u.display_name,
            m.user_id,
            m.first_name,
            m.last_name,
            m.description,
            m.company_name,
            m.company_website,
            m.phone,
            m.company_address,
            m.scategory,
            m.facebook,
            m.twitter,
            m.linkedin,
            m.youtube,
            m.instagram,
            m.googleplus,
            m.specialties,
            m.company_logo,
            t.user_id,
            t.pack_id 
       FROM $wpdb->users u 
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m ON m.user_id = u.ID 
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->wpuf_transaction t ON t.user_id = u.ID 
       WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
       AND m.meta_value LIKE '%employer%' 
       ORDER BY u.user_registered";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($results as $users) {
    echo $users.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: You could debug it by echoing out the content of $sql and running it in a standalone MySQL client on your development machine.

That way you will easily be able to figure out, if the error is in your code or your query.

Comment: I think i figured it out, all the items prefixed with m are actually meta_keys so i am no wondering how i can select the values for those meta keys.

Comment: You tried running the query using phpmyadmin or some other client to make sure there is a result? Also $users is an array not a primitive type

Comment: Yes i ran it in phpmyadmin and go ( #1054 - Unknown column 'm.first_name' in 'field list' )

Answer (score 0):

try this format.

```
$wpdb->get_results('SQL HERE', OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was i was not referencing my meta_keys correctly.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 
            u.ID,
            u.user_email,
            u.display_name,
            m.user_id,
            m1.meta_value AS first_name,
            m2.meta_value AS last_name,
            m3.meta_value AS descriptions,
            m4.meta_value AS company_name,
            m5.meta_value AS company_website,
            m6.meta_value AS phone,
            m7.meta_value AS company_address,
            m8.meta_value AS scategory,
            m9.meta_value AS facebook,
            m10.meta_value AS twitter,
            m11.meta_value AS linkedin,
            m12.meta_value AS youtube,
            m13.meta_value AS instagram,
            m14.meta_value AS googleplus,
            m15.meta_value AS specialties,
            m16.meta_value AS company_logo,
            t.user_id,
            t.pack_id
       FROM $wpdb->users u 
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m ON (m.user_id = u.ID)
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = u.ID AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m2 ON (m2.user_id = u.ID AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m3 ON (m3.user_id = u.ID AND m3.meta_key = 'description')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m4 ON (m4.user_id = u.ID AND m4.meta_key = 'company_name')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m5 ON (m5.user_id = u.ID AND m5.meta_key = 'company_website')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m6 ON (m6.user_id = u.ID AND m6.meta_key = 'phone')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m7 ON (m7.user_id = u.ID AND m7.meta_key = 'company_address')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m8 ON (m8.user_id = u.ID AND m8.meta_key = 'scategory')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m9 ON (m9.user_id = u.ID AND m9.meta_key = 'facebook')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m10 ON (m10.user_id = u.ID AND m10.meta_key = 'twitter')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m11 ON (m11.user_id = u.ID AND m11.meta_key = 'linkedin')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m12 ON (m12.user_id = u.ID AND m12.meta_key = 'youtube')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m13 ON (m13.user_id = u.ID AND m13.meta_key = 'instagram')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m14 ON (m14.user_id = u.ID AND m14.meta_key = 'googleplus')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m15 ON (m15.user_id = u.ID AND m15.meta_key = 'specialties')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m16 ON (m16.user_id = u.ID AND m16.meta_key = 'company_logo')
       INNER JOIN $wpdb->wpuf_transaction t ON t.user_id = u.ID
       WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
       AND m.meta_value LIKE '%employer%' 
       ORDER BY u.ID";
```